# How to adjust a href="#object"

Tags: html, css

When using name="object" and then having the page scroll to that object using a href="#object" id it possible to adjust where the page lands. Rather than the top of the window, a few pixels down. I have a fixed navigation bar that when scrolling, the content goes behind so the nav bar is always visible. So when I use a href="#object" part of it is cut off because it is behind the nav bar. 
Any fixes? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the top padding and margin styling on the element with the named anchor. For example, if your header is 100 pixels tall, give your named anchor a margin-top of -100px and a padding-top of 100px.

See this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/BGzu5/)**.

In this example, the link will bring the bolded text ('Vestibulum ante ipsum') 100px from the top of the page.

Comment: Clever solution. I suggest you put the styling in a CSS class, or even better: target them with `a[name]`!

Comment: Yes, separate the CSS from the HTML obviously. The jsFiddle was just for demo purposes.

Answer (score 2):

And if you want to set these properties (like mentioned from j08691) via a css selector, put this JS into your html, then you're able to give every anchor a class for it, if attribute-selectors don't work (older browsers):

```
function findAnchors(){
    anker = document.anchors;
    for(i=0; i<anker.length; i++ ){
        anker[i].className = "anchor";
    }
}
window.onload = findAnchors();
```

Comment: You don't need to actually use JavaScript for this. [The specification states](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-7577272) that `document.anchors` is "a collection of all the anchor (`A`) elements in a document with a value for the `name` attribute". You can do the same with CSS: `a[name] { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [jQuery.localScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.be/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html) by setting an `offset` in the plugin configuration.

Here, [have a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/FXfqS/).

Comment: Why add the entire jQuery library for something so easily done with CSS? Plus, the question isn't tagged with jQuery.

Comment: @j08691 Because I couldn't come up with a pure CSS solution like yours.